# Use nav.push with side menu in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I try to make a little app in `ionic2` to learn about it but I have a problem with navigation.

In fact I have well understand the difference between a `rootpage` (change whit `nav.setRoot`) and a "normal" page (add with `nav.push`). The thing is for my app I'll need to be able to open a side menu (this is ok if I'm on a `rootpage` but not it's not ok with the second type of page) and to be able to go back (this is ok with a push page but not with a rootpage).

So for me this type of page should be push and not a root page but how repear side menu on this type of page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT:**

What about using `persistent="true"` in your `ion-menu` item? Like you can see in Ionic2 docs:

> Persistent Menus Persistent menus display the MenuToggle button in the
>   NavBar on all pages in the navigation stack. To make a menu persistent
>   set persistent to true on the  element. Note that this will
>   only affect the MenuToggle button in the NavBar attached to the Menu
>   with persistent set to true, any other MenuToggle buttons will not be
>   affected.

So your `app.html` woul be:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true">

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
      <button menuClose ion-item (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @sebaferreras This opens the menu but it is one layer under the pushed page

Comment: @ESturzenegger what do you mean by *one layer under the pushed page*?

Comment: @sebaferreras Let's say I have a menu entry ENTRY1 that i click. now I click on that page a link which pushes ENTRY1_1 page onto the nav stack. By clicking now on the menu button on ENTRY1_1 opens the menu but i see it only when i pop ENTRY1_1 and am back on ENTRY1. That's what i mean one layer under the pushed page.

Comment: @sebaferreras I have to adjust something written up there: The following scenario makes this behaviour happen... LoginPage -> ENTRY1Page -> ENTRY1_1Page -> open Menu (now the menu is opened on ENTRY1Page). So I have 3 pages pushed on the stack and it seems to handle only till 2 pages normally with the sidemenu. Furthermore the third page logs a nav stack of only 1 view (itself) in an Object of OverlayPortal. Very strange...

Comment: Ok it's fixed lol... The problem was that I pushed the third page from a modal and then dismissed it instead of dismissing first and then pushing