# Angular 2 Inheritance to enable disable Ionic Menu Swipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**My problem:**

My application contains a menu which is swipe enabled. On login screen if I swipe I can see the menu which is not right. I want to disable menu swipe for pages that doesn't contains menu icon, like login, inner details pages containing back button, etc.

**Solution found:**

I am able to do that by following the SO link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38654644/2193918

I created a base class and injected a menu object in it. Override `ionViewDidEnter()` and `ionViewDidLeave()` In sub class, I inherited the base class. I have to write `super()` call in derived class constructor and pass the menu object back to the super class.

Is their any other way of doing it as with this way I will have to do this in every single page.

Please check the snippet of code as below:

**Base class**

```
import { MenuController } from "ionic-angular";

export class BaseComponent {
    constructor(public menu: MenuController) {

    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
    }

    ionViewDidLeave() {
        this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
    }
}
```

**Derived class**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController, Events, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
        selector: 'login',
        templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
    })

export class login extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(public menu: MenuController) {
        super(menu)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though what @trichetriche says is true, there's a better way to handle this in Ionic! The answer is **Custom decorators**.

### **[Github repo with working demo.](https://github.com/sebaferreras/Ionic3-CustomDecorators)**

---

First, you'll need to go to the `app.module.ts` file and replace this line

```
export class AppModule { }
```

by this:

```
export class AppModule {

    static injector: Injector;

    constructor(injector: Injector) {    
        // Make the injector to be available in the entire module
        AppModule.injector = injector;    
    }
}
```

Doing that will help us to inject the instance of the `MenuController` in our custom decorator.

We're now able to write our custom decorator. I've created a folder named `CustomDecorators` and a file inside, `disable-side-menu.decorator.ts` with this content (I think the code is pretty self-explanatory):

```
// Angular
import { AppModule } from "../path/to.../app.module";

// Ionic
import { MenuController } from "ionic-angular";

export function DisableSideMenu() {

    return function (constructor) {
        const originalDidEnter = constructor.prototype.ionViewDidEnter;
        const originalWillLeave = constructor.prototype.ionViewWillLeave;            

        constructor.prototype.ionViewDidEnter = function () {

            // Get the MenuController instance
            const menuCtrl = AppModule.injector.get(MenuController);

            // Disable the side menu when entering in the page
            menuCtrl.enable(false);

            console.log('Disabling side menu...');

            // Call the ionViewDidEnter event defined in the page
            originalDidEnter && typeof originalDidEnter === 'function' && originalDidEnter.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        constructor.prototype.ionViewWillLeave = function () {

            // Get the MenuController instance
            const menuCtrl = AppModule.injector.get(MenuController);

            // Enable the side menu when leaving the page
            menuCtrl.enable(true);

            console.log('Enabling side menu...');

            // Call the ionViewWillLeave event defined in the page
            originalWillLeave && typeof originalWillLeave === 'function' && originalWillLeave.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }

}
```

**That's it!** If you want to disable the side menu in a particular page, you'd need to add our custom decorator like this:

```
import { DisableSideMenu } from '../the/path/to../custom-decorators/disable-side-menu.decorator';

@DisableSideMenu()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-demo-page',
    templateUrl: 'demo-page.html'
})
...
```

So you don't need to extend any `BaseClass` nor inject anything else, making this extremely easy to be reused.

Comment: I implemented the code above as given. But while running ionic serve, I am getting a Runtime error on browser. 

__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__app_app_module__.a is undefined

Comment: Did you added this import in the `app.module.ts`?: `import { Injector } from '@angular/core';`. Please let me know if the error persists and I'll create a demo app in Github so you can take a look at the code.

Comment: Yes, I have added the import in App Module file

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I've fixed it by moving the `const menuCtrl = AppModule.injector.get(MenuController);` line inside of the function. Could you please try now?. In a few minutes, I'll add a link to a Github demo with the decorator working properly.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thanks!. I think this is the much better solution.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) @Jassi

Comment: @sebaferreras thank you, I learnt something new reading your answer :O

Comment: Just a question if you mind : are decorators just functions ? How do one declare a function as a decorator ?

Comment: Glad to hear that @trichetriche :) Yes, they're just functions. You can find some more information **[here](https://netbasal.com/inspiration-for-custom-decorators-in-angular-95aeb87f072c)**.

Comment: @Jassi I've seen the proposed edit to use `ionViewWillLeave` instead of `ionViewDidLeave`. Is that because of an error/bug when using `ionViewDidLeave`?

Comment: Yes its a bug, ionViewDidLeave is called before ionViewDidEnter, so the issue is for first page the menu is disabled which works fine, but when you go to inner page it gets enabled again as the ionViewDidEnter of second page called first and then ionViewDidLeave of Page1 which again enables it.

Comment: @sebaferreras +1 for this and something new I learnt. One more thing is like when the user logins I have `this.navCtrl.push(ActionPage)` Now a back button appears I tried `this.navCtrl.setRoot(ActionPage)` but this time nothing appears on the Action page. Please suggest.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @User :). May I ask what do you mean by _but this time nothing appears on the Action page._?

Comment: @sebaferreras I mean when I use `this.navCtrl.setRoot(ActionPage)` then I cannot see either Menu nor back button. I loose the buttons. How can I show Menu button when user got logged in.

Comment: Oh, I see. Please take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905597/use-nav-push-with-side-menu-in-ionic-2/37905896#37905896)**. The key to show the menu toggle is to add the `persistent="true"` attribute, like this: `<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true">...</ion-menu>` @User

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : **no**. Inheriting a class implies that you have to call super in your constructor. If you don't want to do that, then you need to find another way of doing this.

Comment: After lot of search on Google, I posted the question. If you know any alternate solution then please guide or refer a link. I will be very thankful.

Comment: Actually that is the best solution ! I'm not saying you're doing wrong, I'm saying if you want to stop writing super, then you have to find another solution. But after all, that's just one word, and it allow you to see in the blink of an eye that you have some logic through it. I would keep doing that if I were you !