# Correct approach to enable or disable sidemenu on certain pages in Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have gone through this SO link [Ionic - How to remove sidemenu on login page only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165972/ionic-how-to-remove-sidemenu-on-login-page-only) 
and tried the solutions provided here. Based on the solutions provided in the above link it seems like the simplest way to remove sidemenu
from certain pages in Ionic 3 is to use the following code snippet in each page.

**login.ts, register.ts, forgot-password.ts  (all the files NOT requiring sidemenu)**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private menu: MenuController) {
    this.menu.enable(false);
}
```

**home.ts, account-settings.ts (all the files requiring sidemenu)**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private menu: MenuController) {
    this.menu.enable(true);
}
```

Based on the above SO solution provided I had to go in each of the page and disable the sidemenu by setting the flag as false and viceversa for the pages requiring sidemenu.

Is this a better approach than this?

Comment: look in to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938361/8850397

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use menuToggle directive like so:

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button menuToggle="false">
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Basically adding it to those pages you need top left corner button to show up and setting it to false for the pages you don't want users to see button calling side menu

Comment: Is it possible that the back button will override this menu icon ?

Comment: hmm, I think I might not truly understand your use case;/ Can you describe in more details the behavior you want to achieve? in case the page is "pushed" into the navStack with MenyToggle=false - the back button will still appear.

Comment: I was just trying to understand what happens to the Back button when have a sidemenu icon  also?  Which one takes precendence?

Comment: Back Button takes precedence, from UX perspective user is in a "pushed in" page, so to access side menu they need to go back first then once they are at the root page they see the burger menu